# Install flash for Interner Explorer for non administrators

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, flash

A computer on our network is logged into by a member of staff who is not an administrative user.  When I install flash player for him I am prompted to enter the credentials of an administrative user.  I proceed to do this and flash installs fine.  But it doesn't seem to be installed for that user (pages with flash on them in IE do not show the flash content, rather they show the message that flash player is not installed)

So my guess is that by giving it administrative credentials it installs flash under the local profile for the administrative user.

Is there a way (other than temporarily making the non administrative user an administrator on that machine) to get it to install for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Flash is installed per machine and not per user. So you can't ignore the UAC prompt.

Comment: I'm not trying to ignore it.  I'm trying to get flash to work for the user it needs to work for.   So if it's per machine then the issue is that flash isn't working after being installed.

Comment: use Chrome, which install to the AppData folder (so no UAC prompt)  and includes always the latest flash version. Because of your rude reply you no longer get help from me.

Comment: The users affected do use Chrome to get around it,  but there are some things that don't work in Chrome so they tend to prefer IE (I know, idiots :) )   I was asked to get flash working in IE to make things a bit easier.